# Iterating datetime function over a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timedelta

I am using Python 2.7 within another application. I have a list of timestamps in the following format. The length of the list will vary per task:

```
['23:05:26', '23:05:28', '23:05:30', '23:05:32']
```

Using `datetime` I would like to run some basic maths on this list making use of `timedelta`

So far I have successfully run the operation on two individual timestamps, but I cannot find the correct syntax and or method to iterate the same function over a list.

My basic function is

```
def TS(x): 
    z1 = datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S')
    z2 = timedelta(hours=z1.hour,minutes=z1.minute,seconds=z1.second)
```

When the strings are converted to `timedelta`s I plan to perform the following calculation (but not sure if it should be in the same loop as setting the `timedelta`):

```
x[-1] - x[-2], x[-2] - x[-3], ...
```

and then store the result of each of these calculations as both a string, using `str(ResultOfTimeCalc)`, and also as seconds, which I guess I should do using `ResultOfTimeCalc.seconds`.

How can I format this all, what needs to be done in a loop, and how to iterate a function within a loop?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to call `timedelta` explicitly. You can subtract two `datetime` objects to get the difference as a `timedelta`.

```
>>> times = ['23:05:26', '23:05:28', '23:05:30', '23:05:32']
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> tses = [datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S') for x in times]
>>> [y - x for x, y in zip(tses, tses[1:])]
[datetime.timedelta(seconds=2), datetime.timedelta(seconds=2), datetime.timedelta(seconds=2)]
```

Comment: nice answer, but I have fewer lines! lol